# jQuery fullcalendar Overlap events in z index

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Any idea if it is possible not to overlap in any way events in FullCalendar? I don't mean like putting them one next to the other, I mean putting them one top of the other with a z-index, even if one would become hidden behind another. 
I only managed to put them side by side but this does not fit my need. 
The existing slotEventOverlap attribute still changes the way events are rendered and I don't want that.

Comment: you mean you want to stack events directly on top of each other? In that case how will the user know if there are multiple events covering the same time period? What do you think would be the benefit of this? It seems to me that information which might be important to the user would be invisible. Anyway fullCalendar does not support that, as you've discovered - probably because - as I've just described - it's not really very user-friendly.

Comment: I am planning on adding a filter based on event types (different type has a different css class ... blue, green, red etc...) ... and with the filter just to eliminate events based on what I select.

Comment: ok but what does that have to do with stacking events on top of each other in the display? I can't see how that is related, or how the stacking idea helps with that?